# Modify particular items in array while traversing in reverse order in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, reverse, traversal

Is there a way to modify particular array elements (based on some condition) while traversing it in reverse order in Ruby?

To be more clear lets say,

problem is replace even numbers in [1,2,3,4,5] with x

output should be [1,x,3,x,5] (same array) but replace should happen from right to left..traversing from 5 to 1.

Thanks in Advance!

This works: **(arr.length -1).downto(0) { |x| do something with arr[x] }**

Comment: You mean like collect! but in reverse ?

Comment: yes exactly, i have noticed that map, collect work from left to right because they in turn depend on each but i want to modify from right to left..i just want to know is there any existing way to do it instead of writing custom code. to traverse we have reverse_each but couldn't find anything to modify :(

Comment: is there a reason you cant just use `my_array.reverse.map{}` ? if you want to put it back in order again just add another `.reverse` to the end

Comment: but you don't want the output reserved, right? only the traverse order must be in reverse? and you want the updates always in-place?

Comment: @Isotope reverse is an additional performance overhead which i want to avoid.

Comment: @tokland yes i want array to be as is..but should modify the elements traversing in reverse order

Comment: @mssrivatsa: ok, then check my answer, it does what I understand you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
p [1,2,3,4,5].reverse_each.map{|e| e.odd? ? e : e/2} #[5, 2, 3, 1, 1]
```

Comment: but this reverses the array and it's not inplace, I think that's what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to traverse in reverse order, not get the output also reversed. Maybe this:

```
xs = [1, 2, 3]
xs.reverse_each.with_index { |x, idx| xs[xs.size-1-idx] = x.to_s if x == 2 }
xs #=> [1, "2", 3]
```

Comment: `xs` won't look like you show when using `map` instead of `map!`.

Comment: @Michael: oops, yes, it's a enumerator... uhhmm, maybe with each.

Comment: @tokland Thanks! It works :) I couldn't think of it because i wanted to avoid index based access..Looks like it cant be avoided.

Comment: @tokland But should be careful while using this because the index starts from 0
lets say your x is 3 but if u try replacing using xs[idx] 1 is modified because ur idx for x = 3 is 0 in this case..please correct me if i am wrong :)

Comment: indeed, fixed, the index must be also "reversed"

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate and love Ruby's humane syntax, but you may want to consider more verbose options such as:

```
ary = [1,2,3,4,5]
i = ary.count - 1
while i >= 0 do
    ary[i] = "x" if ary[i] % 2 == 0
    i -= 1
end
puts ary.join(",")
```